# Is imagedestroy() required when you only process a single image?

Tags: php, gd

I'm using PHP to process some image using GD extension. The code structure is rather complicated, images are allocated "deep" in the code and there are many IF's that simply bail-out. The script only processes a single image, and once it writes it to the file it exits.

I guess I could use try...catch instead, but I'm interested to know whether it is really needed to call imagedestroy() or PHP's garbage collector would free it when script ends?

Comment: unless your really need the resources back before the end of the script, i wouldn't, but then it wont hurt if you do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need to call this function, but it's a good practice because images can be large and if you are in a crowded environment every kilobyte counts.

Comment: 2022, function has [no effect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php).