# Do I must use imagedestroy?

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I'm beginner PHP Dev.

I get file in folder and convert its in to base64.
`src='data:image/jpg;base64,".$img."'`

I see `imagecreatefromjpeg()`. I think, It must use `imagedestroy()` for free memory.

Do I must use `imagedestroy($img)` after `src='data:image/jpg;base64,".$img."'` ?

Comment: Unless you're using any of the `image**`-functions to create an image resource (which you don't seem to be doing) then no, you shouldn't use that function. If you just want to free up memory, just unset the variable after you're finished using it: `unset($img);`. That isn't specific for images but for variables in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is imagedestroy() required when you only process a single image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623260/is-imagedestroy-required-when-you-only-process-a-single-image)